# How many concurrent request can tomcat handle by Default

Tags: java, tomcat

How many requests Tomcat7.0.42 handle at a time.Can we configure the same in any external File.If so where.

Comment: I think maxCOnnections is not for handling simultaneous request.Please have a look at other answers too...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends on the type connector you are using to accept the requests. There is parameter called `maxConnections` in `server.xml` that can be configured to throttle the number of incoming requests. Here is the [description of maxConnections params  for Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html):

> The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and
>   process at any given time. When this number has been reached, the
>   server will not accept any more connections until the number of
>   connections falls below this value. The operating system may still
>   accept connections based on the acceptCount setting. Default value
>   varies by connector type. For BIO the default is the value of
>   maxThreads unless an Executor is used in which case the default will
>   be the value of maxThreads from the executor. For NIO the default is
>   10000. For APR/native, the default is 8192.
>
> Note that for APR/native on Windows, the configured value will be
>   reduced to the highest multiple of 1024 that is less than or equal to
>   maxConnections. This is done for performance reasons. If set to a
>   value of -1, the maxConnections feature is disabled and connections
>   are not counted

Comment: maxConnections define maximum number of connections server accepts not the maximum number of requests handled simultaneously

Comment: @Prateek No it doesn't. You are arguing with the Tomcat documentation here, which Juned has quoted. What you are referring to is a combination of 'acceptCount' and the listen backlog queue.

Comment: @EJP but on tomcat documentation page which i have mentioned in my answer specifies maxThreads.please help me to get clearity if i m wrong... :)

Comment: The extract cited above seems perfectly clear and includes maxThreads as a special case. Your own extract is only a partial quote.

Answer (score 20):

In **`server.xml`** file you specify **`maxThreads`** which `specifies maximum number of simultaneous requests that can be handled..`

```
<Connector port="8080" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="4443" acceptCount="100"
               debug="0" connectionTimeout="60000" 
               disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

***In Tomcat 7,***

**`The maximum number of request processing threads to be created by this Connector, which therefore determines the maximum number of simultaneous requests that can be handled. If not specified, this attribute is set to 200.`**

***EDIT*** : If an executor is associated with this connector, this attribute is ignored as the connector will execute tasks using the executor rather than an internal thread pool.

For more info, refer this link [Tomcat 7 Doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: You left out the final sentence about the attribute being ignored if an Executor is defined.

Comment: updated my answer, it means maxThread value is used in maxConnections.

Comment: What is the upper limit of request Tomcat can handle?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat's connectors can be configured to only service a certain number of requests simultaneously -- that's configured as the maxConnections attribute of a  in server.xml