# Establishing multiple TCP connections simultaneously

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

My understanding of TCP in Java is that, while you can multithread handling data transmissions on a socket, you can only establish one connection at a time. Is this true? If not, how would you implement a server that can establish multiple connections simultaneously on the same address and port.

i.e If a client was to try and establish a connection to the server, but is connecting over a very unstable network, would the server have to wait for the connection handshake to complete before being able to accept a connection from another client?

Comment: The standard pattern for a server is that the code listens for a connection, and then when it receives one, it forks a new thread.  The new thread communicates with the client, and the server's main thread goes back and listens for another connection.  This is how I've always seen it done in Unix/Linux.  It's not Java-specific.  It's probably very similar on Windows systems, but I don't recall offhand.

Comment: P.S. I don't know the answer to the second question, but I'm guessing that yes, the server would have to wait for one connection to be established (or abandoned) before accepting another.  That's a function of the underlying OS and/or the TCP protocol itself, and again has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: @ajb The underlying OS is able to send packets simultaneously to multiple recipients, therefore initiating multiple connections at once. There would be terrible performance implications if there was such a sequential communication.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers guys. From Andy's and Kayaman's answers and some reading, it looks like TCP allows multiple half-open connections to be created simultaneously up to some limit (max determined by the OS). Still not sure about how the queue is handled though. If it is a _backlog_, then wouldn't the first connection in the queue need to be resolved before the other half-open connections can be processed, or does this depend on the server implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a client was to try and establish a connection to the server, but is connecting over a very unstable network, would the server have to wait for the connection handshake to complete before being able to accept a connection from another client?

This aspect of the TCP protocol is addressed by the [listen backlog](http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/023/2333/2333s2.html). On linux at least, half-open connections for a server are queued pending completion after which they are ready to accept. The maximum number of half-open connections that a server can handle is capped by the OS. On Linux you can see what the cap is by examining a `/proc` entry. For example on a RHEL 6 VM:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn 
128
```

A malicious entity can exploit this by launching a [SYN_FLOOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=SYN_flood) attack that will fill up the listen backlog and prevent your server from accepting new connections. Mitigating this type of attack (especially when performed by a botnet) is extremely difficult but there are some [basic defences](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2014/04/11/mitigate-tcp-syn-flood-attacks-with-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-beta/) as well as some expensive paid services out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer the JAVA based server implementation thread architecture, most of the server uses a pool and queue based thread. We cannot create N number of thread for each request. But the server maintains a queue of requests with thread pool architecture and process the requests one by one.

Therefore If you are thinking about creating your own JAVA based server. Then plan for creating configurable thread queues and handle the request.

Refer [How many concurrent request can tomcat handle by Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372464/how-many-concurrent-request-can-tomcat-handle-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

The server socket isn't forced to wait for a single socket to finish connecting before accepting other connections. While it's waiting for the TCP messages from one endpoint, it can just as easily wait for messages from another.

There was a flaw in TCP earlier that allowed a simple DOS attack by just initiating connections without finishing them, but even that required numerous connections.