# How to accept fixed number of requests concurrently in Http inbound-gateway?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, concurrency, spring-integration

I am using Tomcat and I have `http:inbound-gateway`  as gateway and channel named `request` configured as it's request channel. Sometimes there are lots of requests on my service which cause occurring `Too many open files` Error which comes from OS.
I tried to make `request` channel a `QueChannel` and set capacity for it but it does not work. Then I tried to set `request` channel as a polling-consumer channel and set a poller with fixed-delay to poll and it did not work again. Is there a conventional way to limit number of input requests?
And how can I customize response in discarded requests?

```
<int:channel id="request">
  <int:queue capacity="100"/>
</int:channel>    
...
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="RESTServiceGateway"
                        supported-methods="GET"
                        request-channel="request"
                        error-channel="errorResolver" />

<int:chain input-channel="request" output-channel="response">
<int:poller fixed-delay="1" max-messages-per-poll=""/>
...
```

Or

```
<task:executor id="requestExecutor" pool-size="1-10" queue-capacity="10"/>
<int:channel id="request">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="requestExecutor"/>
</int:channel>
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="RESTServiceGateway"
                        supported-methods="GET"
                        request-channel="request"
                        error-channel="errorResolver" />

<int:chain input-channel="request" output-channel="response">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`Too many open files` is not related to your integration flow configuration. This is about opened sockets from the HTTP clients to your Tomcat. This one is already concurrent and can handle many requests in parallel. Therefore I would say that your paralleling logic in the flow doesn't bring too much value and definitely doesn't effect a number of opened sockets.

You can configure concurrency in Tomcat though: [`maxConnections` in `server.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372464/how-many-concurrent-request-can-tomcat-handle-by-default) .

Another option is to increase an amount for those opened file on your Linux using `ulimit` tool: https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/